# Exception while retrieve a null field from sql ce 3.5

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I am storing an image in a table in varbinary(max) format, actually first time it will be empty, I am checking whether it is empty of not but while checking for null field I am getting any exception stating invalid cast so can any one suggest what is the problem with this.

code sample is

```
 con = new SqlCeConnection(CommonClass.ConnectionStringStartup);
                        con.Open();

                        SqlCeCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Signature,UserId FROM UserMaster Where " +
                            " LoginName = '" + UserName + "' " +
                            " AND Password = '" + Password + "'";
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                       // MessageBox.Show(UserName);

                        SqlCeDataReader dr;
                        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

                            if (dr.Read())
                            {

                                if (dr.IsDBNull(0))
                                    SignLoaded = false;
                                else
                                    SignLoaded = true;

                            }
```

Thanks in advance

With regards
Bharath kumar

Comment: Some code showing how you check for Null would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like this should work?

Have you tried Convert.IsDbNull( dr.GetValue(0))?

Otherwise I can only suggest using dr.GetValue(0) and look at the result.

Cheers